# Arrays going out of Bounds in java

Tags: java, arrays

I created a simple method which takes array size for user and enters data into array and print the array, but this code is always giving out of bounds error pls help.
Here's the code.

```
static void arrrays()
{
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
        arrays = stores multiples values of similar variables

        WAYS TO DECLEAR A ARRAY
        1.String[] cars = new String[3];
        2.String[] cars={"Camaro","Corvette","Tesla"};

    */

    int size;
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array =");
    size=sn.nextInt();

    int[] num= new int[size];

    System.out.println("Created a Numerical Array");

    for (int x=0;x<=num.length;x++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter data into the " + x + " index = " );
        num[x]=sn.nextInt();

    }
    for(int j=0;j<=num.length;j++)
    {
        int temp2=j+1;
        System.out.println(temp2 +" index contains= "+num[j]);
    }


    /*//Printing arrays
    String[] cars={"Camaro","Corvette","Tesla"};

    for(int i=0;i< cars.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(cars[i]);
    }*/

}
```

Comment: How many numbers are there between 0 and `size`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0):

Looping over an Array / List via indexed access always needs to implement the check to be

```
i < array.length
```

and NOT

```
i <= array.length //Out of Bounds!
```

Imagine this array: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` now the length will be `5`. But `array[5]` is out of bounds because the indices start at `0`. Thus you need to check for your index to be small than the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered more than once ([for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775607/22748368))

You are exceeding array length when asking for values.
Your code is asking for one more value than the array can store.

Just change the

```
for(int x = 0; x <= num.length; x++)
```

to

```
for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
```

in both cases so it does not overflow your array length when reaching the end of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a runtime exception in Java that occurs when you try to access an array with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array. In order to fix this error in your code.

Change `i <= array.length` to `i < array.length`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);

    int size;
      System.out.println ("Enter the size of the array =");
      size = sn.nextInt ();
    int[] num = new int[size];

      System.out.println ("Created a Numerical Array");

    for (int x = 0; x < num.length; x++)
      {
    System.out.println ("Enter data into the " + x + " index = ");
    num[x] = sn.nextInt ();

      }
    for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++)
      {
    int temp2 = j + 1;
    System.out.println (temp2 + " index contains= " + num[j]);
      }

  }
}
```

Refer the working code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/DYQ_qO3tL)